# 1.5hr connecting flight in Toronto

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, short-connections, yyz, pre-clearance

[image]

I'm traveling from PDX to TLV roundtrip from June to August this summer and ended up on some 3rd party airfare sites. I found the above fare on Cheapoair and have a few questions.

Is the 1.5hr connection when returning (TLV to YYZ) possible? I'm not sure if I would have to go through immigration at that point since the flight after that is back to the USA (I have an American passport).

In addition, is this fare considered to be on a single ticket? Will I have to recheck my bags at one of the steps on the way to TLV if I check them beginning at PDX?

Comment: In my limited experience, the customs & immigration experience at YYZ has gotten a lot smoother over the last couple of years, due to a major re-design of the traffic flow for connecting flights.  (For example, you used to have to re-clear security when connecting to the US from Canada, but you don't any more.)  But I haven't been through there enough times to know if my experiences were a fluke, and I've never connected from International–US via YYZ.  (Which is why this a comment and not an answer.)

Comment: Thanks Michael! Hopefully somebody else can chime in with their recent experiences

Answer (score 2):

That's a doable connection, but it's tight.  You'll be clearing customs and immigration twice at YYZ (Pearson, Toronto) - once for Canada, once for the US (pre-clearance).  You will need to reclear security after clearing US customs and immigration.  (Canada is moving at some airports to not require this after re-entering Canada, but the US so far has not followed suit.)  This means if there's any delay, you'll be at risk of missing your connecting flight home.

I'd strongly recommend a longer connection.  This one is possible, but it's fraught with danger and you'll need to move fast.  (If you have NEXUS and/or Global Entry, that will help; the former will help with both customs passes, the latter only with the US, but it will still help.)

Comment: Canadian formalities will be handled at US customs in Person. Furthermore, airlines don’t design itineraries that are not feasible. Air Canada in particular is very aggressively going after the intercontinental to US flight market and they are trying to be very competitive with regards to total itinerary travel times which means short but well managed connections. The opinion to seek a longer connections is from my view too risk adverse to be pragmatic.

Comment: My post states that US Customs and Immigration is cleared at the Canadian airport (I'll clarify this) and that's why the time limit is more of an issue.  There are two clearances to be made in one stop.  Yes, it's a legal connection but speaking from experience, it's tight.  (My very post started with "That's a doable connection, but it's tight"; I'm not sure how much clearer I can be.)

Comment: The [YYZ airport website has a tool that tells you what to expect for transfers](https://www.torontopearson.com/Connecting.aspx). Note that your answer is only correct if one flight (or both) are at YYZ terminal 3. If both the international arrival and US departure are in terminal 1 [he'll clear US immigration alone](https://www.aircanada.com/ca/en/aco/home/fly/at-the-airport/airport-information/toronto-pearson-international-airport/int-us.html).

Answer (score 1):

https://www.aircanada.com/us/en/aco/home/plan/check-in-information/minimum-connection-times.html

shows the minimum connection time in YYZ for "international to US" to be 1 hour and 25 minutes. So your connection is "legal" but it's right on the edge.

In practices this means: if all goes well (no delays, no major lines at immigration/customs) you will make the connection. If you don't, Air Canada will rebook you on the next available flight to PDX for free.